# masking out triangle at bottom of image

Tags: html, css

Trying to mask out a bottom triangle from a div with an image inside. (I want to see the image in the triangle) horizontal in middle pointing down

html

```
<div id="last-img">
    . . . image here . . .  
</div>
```

css

```
#last-img { 
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  border-color: white transparent white white; 
}

#last-img::before,
#last-img::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px; left:auto;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}

#last-img::before {
  top: -10px;
  bottom: 50%;
}

#last-img::after {
  top: 50%;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Perhap syou could show us the **intended** result. At the moment your request is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  border: 12px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-color: white transparent;
  border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: white transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: exactly! Is this based on width's or heights, Its 100% width and the height isn't in my control

Comment: The size of the arrow is based on the 20px value I used to demo.

Comment: I apologize I meant none of size/location is based on the size of the div

Answer (score 0):

For a single, solid color triangle, only one pseudo element is required (before or after, take your pick).

```css
#last-img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#last-img::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="last-img">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
</div>
```

Comment: not looking for a solid triangle bottom, more like masked out of the image